# Spring @CrossOrigin not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cors, cross-domain

I'm using spring-web for building a json/rest backend for my web/mobile application. 
I was using javax.servlet.Filter, adding appropriate cors header:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, accept, authorization, content-type");
        response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

Now i'm trying to upgrade to spring 4.2.5 and use @CrossOrigin annotation, but it seems that OPTION dispatched response doesn't contains appropriate headers.

Here my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "it.foo.api.rest", useDefaultFilters = false, 
    includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = Controller.class, type = FilterType.ANNOTATION))
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
//          .allowCredentials(true)
//          .allowedOrigins("*")
//          .maxAge(3600)
//          .allowedMethods("PUT", "POST", "GET", "OPTIONS", "DELETE")
//          .allowedHeaders("content-type", "authorization", "x-requested-with", "accept", "origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers")
//          .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
//          .exposedHeaders("x-requested-with, accept, authorization, content-type");
    }
```

as you can see i've tryed some configurations.

My controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(allowCredentials="true", 
    methods={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.PUT,RequestMethod.OPTIONS,RequestMethod.DELETE},
    allowedHeaders={"x-requested-with", "accept", "authorization", "content-type"}, 
    exposedHeaders={"access-control-allow-headers", "access-control-allow-methods", "access-control-allow-origin", "access-control-max-age", "X-Frame-Options"})
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/admin")
public class AdminUserController extends BaseController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST,  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public HttpEntity<AdminUserResource> postLogin(@RequestBody AdminLoginCredentials credentials) {
        return new ResponseEntity<AdminUserResource>(..., HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Again i've tested with several configuration, with only basic @CrossOrigin annotation.

Headers WITH servlet filter (old version): [image]

Headers WITHOUT filter and WITH @CrossOrigin (new version, not working):  [image]

i can't find out what i'm missing!

Comment: Did you add `dispatchOptionsRequest` to initial parameters of `DispatcherServlet` in `web.xml`?

Comment: options are dispatched but with wrong headers.

Comment: after spending several hours of debug, i've notice that my gradle's dependencies were for some reason corrupted and eclipse was using newest version (4.2.5) but when gradle deploys it was deploying older version of spring (4.0). 
Now i've used 1 more hour to move project from gradle to maven :/

Comment: Same problem here.And I found the root of the problem. When using the CrossOrigin annotation, spring is mapping the resulting CORS configuration  to the annotated Java method, and when receiving a rest call, it will retrieve this call, and search for the CORS configuration associated.

But when you're doing an OPTIONS call, it's not your controller method which is called but rather the `RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping$HttpOptionsHandler.handle()` method...  which have no CorsConfiguration registered...

I am currently searching for a solution.